# how to create charts using jquery with data having more columns

Tags: jquery

I have the following data.
How do I create a bar chart and pie chart using this?

```
Fiscal Year    Total Budget   Average Budget    Number of States Reporting   Average Budget % Change

 2001-2002      $81,337,970    $77,365,083                $8                         11.00%

 2002-2003      $78,329,957    $59,330,670                $93                         7.00%
```

I am new to jQuery and I need this to be done in jQuery.

Comment: here Fiscal Year,    Total Budget,   Average Budget,    Number of States Reporting,   Average Budget % Change
all are different columns.

Comment: http://www.flotcharts.org/ - Try this plugin

Comment: thanks for everything. i have a small doubt can we plot all these values on a single graph if so how. give me some example please?

Comment: my problem is as am new to jquery i want to know how to create charts using jquery to the data as i mentioned above using the data from the database. i have seen many links but am unable to find what i require. can any one understand my problem and help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

You usually have to give json datas into these charts :

JSON (JavaScript Object Notification) is a hash of pair-values keys.

so for example :

```
var data = [

    { 
         "period" : "2001-2002", 
         "totalBudget" : 81337970,
         "avgBudget" : 77365083,
         "numberStates" : 8,
         "avgBudgetChange" :  11.00 
    },
    {
         "period" : "2002-2003", 
         "totalBudget" : 78329957,
         "avgBudget" : 58330670,
         "numberStates" : 93,
         "avgBudgetChange" :  7.00
    }


 ]
```

To access to a particular data : `data[0].period //will output "2001-2002"`

If you have to get these datas from server-side :

with PHP for example, you want first to encode your array into json with the function `json_encode(data); // will encode an array into json`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Then do an XMLHttpRequest : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ , http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Then make your chart, adding some options depending on the chart library you use.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for everything. i have a small doubt can we plot all these values on a single graph if so how. give me some example please?